# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string when executing get model object in django

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a model object in django like so...

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
     employee_title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     pk_person_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     department_name = models.CharField(max_length=240)
     cost_center = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user_name

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'company_hr_idm_data_v'
```

and in my view I am doing a simple get on the Person object like so...

```
testobj = Person.objects.using('oracle').get(pk=4)
```

The code errors out with a `DatabaseError` that says

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Here is the stack trace I code when I have my debug mode set to true in my settings.py

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/roles/testing

Django Version: 1.7.2
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'roles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/entitlements/roles/views/Organization.py" in test
  9.     testobj = Person.objects.using('oracle').get(pk=4)
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  351.         num = len(clone)
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  122.         self._fetch_all()
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  966.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  265.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  700.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  786.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py"     in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py"     in execute
65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/adjeibad/.virtualenvs/wwtmlserver/lib/python2.7/site-                    packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py" in execute
  916.             return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /roles/testing
Exception Value: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Oh! also here is the query that is generated...

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS "_RN", "_SUB".* FROM (SELECT "COMPANY_HR_IDM_DATA_V"."EMPLOYEE_TITLE", "COMPANY_HR_IDM_DATA_V"."PK_PERSON_ID", "COMPANY_HR_IDM_DATA_V"."DEPARTMENT_NAME", "COMPANY_HR_IDM_DATA_V"."COST_CENTER", "COMPANY_HR_IDM_DATA_V"."USER_NAME" FROM "COMPANY_HR_IDM_DATA_V" WHERE "COMPANY_HR_IDM_DATA_V"."PK_PERSON_ID" = :arg0) "_SUB" WHERE ROWNUM <= 21) WHERE "_RN" > 0
```

I tried to put as much information as I could, can anyone please steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Does that need to be a statement that needs to be execute before my retrieval of the object? The tickets says that they encountered the problem when working with dates. I am not accessing date information. I do notice that django runs those two queries they mention on app start up.

Comment: You're right, it looks like that ticket isn't actually related. I've deleted that comment to prevent future confusion, though [it's possible this is a bug in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/internals/contributing/bugs-and-features/#reporting-bugs).

Comment: could it be that the table in db was created already and not by the model sync

Comment: The table was created already. All I am trying to do is to read data from it. I have tried creating a model for another table on the database and it works just fine. When I try an access company_hr_idm_data_v it gives me that error and the db user I am using has full access rights

Comment: Then probably the table column pk_person_id is created for string or something but not integer, so when pk=4 is passed which is integer but what is expected is to be string

Comment: I have all my types matching up to the data types in the database. Even the lengths. The funny thing is I did a Person.objects.using('oracle').all() and it gives me the exact same error

Comment: If you run the sql by itself does it generate an error?

Comment: Did you try python manage.py inspectdb to create a model for the table, and then try accessing the table using this new model?

Comment: Can you provide the output of 'desc company_hr_idm_data_v;' from the SQL Plus prompt or Toad or some other SQL shell?  Alternatively, the result of 'select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, data_type_mod, data_length, data_precision, data_scale, nullable from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'company_hr_idm_data_v';'

Answer (score 0):

Can you try executing the Query directly by giving the input?. There might be a datatype difference between the input and the actual column type.